# ¿Como retornar un objeto usando switchMap de rxjs en Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, objeto, observable, rxjs

Estoy trabajando con firestorage de firebase y necesito retornar un objeto usando el operador switchMap, mi codigo es el siguiente.

Este es mi servicio

```
buscarCliente(buscar: string){

    const size$ = new Subject<string>();

    const queryObservable = size$.pipe(switchMap(keyword => {

      return this.afs.collection('entradas', ref => ref.where('nombreProveedor', '==', 
      keyword)).valueChanges()

    }));

    // subscribe to changes
    queryObservable.subscribe(queriedItems => {

      // Objeto a retornar
      return queriedItems;
    });

    // trigger the query
    size$.next(buscar);

  }
```

Y este es el component.ts donde lo llamo, primero quiero hacer un console.log para ver si me imprime el objeto pero me imprime undefined.

```
let a = this.clients_.buscarCliente(this.tienda);
console.log(a);
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Hola. El metodo `buscarCliente(string)` no retorna nada. ¿No seria mejor que retornara el Observable para quien use ese metodo se suscriba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso podrías regresar un `Observable` en el método `buscarCliente` como te comentaron, con esto seria suficiente

```
buscarCliente(buscar: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('entradas', ref => ref.where('nombreProveedor', '==', buscar))
        .valueChanges();
}
```

Después donde se ejecuta el método hacer el `subscribe`

```
this.clients_.buscarCliente(this.tienda)
    .subscribe(resultados => {
        console.log(resultados);
        let a = resultados;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Aquí dentro del `subscribe` te devuelve un `Array` con los resultados encontrados en la búsqueda.

Si la búsqueda esta diseñada para que solo encuentre un resultado, puedes probar con lo siguiente

```
buscarCliente(buscar: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('entradas', ref => ref.where('nombreProveedor', '==', buscar).limit(1))
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(resultados => resultados[0])
        );
}
```

En este caso cuando se hiciera el `subscribe` ya no te devolvería un `Array` sino solo el resultado en un `Object`, o `undefined` sino se encontró nada.

Solo no olvides que cuando haces un `subscribe` hacer también el `unsubscribe`  dentro del `ngOnDestroy` o cuando ya no lo necesites.

Igual si necesitas una búsqueda mas dinámica donde el valor a buscar esta en constante cambio puedes crear una variable que obtenga estos valores

```
busqueda = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```

Y donde detectes el cambio del valor a buscar hacer el `next`

```
this.busqueda.next(buscar);
```

Y ahora donde haces el `subscribe` seria

```
this.busqueda
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(busqueda =>
            this.clients_.buscarCliente(busqueda)
        )
    )
    .subscribe(resultados => {
        console.log(resultados);
        let a = resultados;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```